# Ondatachanged not saving variable values once done

Tags: java, android, firebase

My issue is that when the onDataChange function runs it does not save the values added to events. The events list does exist within the onDataChange but once i try to access the values out side of it, it longer has them. I am not too sure how to fix this.

```
public void saveNewEvent(String uid, String eventId, String eventName, String eventHost,String eventTime, String eventAddress, String eventImage, String eventDescription) {
    savedEventsCreated = false;
    events.clear();

    UserEvents info = new UserEvents(eventName, eventHost, eventTime, eventAddress, eventId, eventImage, eventDescription);
    savedEvents.child("savedEvents").child(eventId).setValue(info);
    users.child(uid).child("eventsList").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                events.add(postSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < events.size(); i++)
        Log.i("Info", events.get(i));
        events.add(eventId);
        users.child(uid).child("eventsList").setValue(events, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                if (databaseError != null) {
                    System.out.println("Data could not be saved " + databaseError.getMessage());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Data saved successfully.");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happening because your `events` list is not defined inside the `onDataChange()` method. To solve this, move the declaration of that list inside `onDataChange()` method, otherwise it will be null. This is happening due the asynchronous behaviour of that method which is called before even you add those values to the list.

If you want to use those values outside the `onDataChange()` method, please see my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152775/how-to-get-value-async-in-outside-method-ondatachange).